# Why does the code after await sometimes run on another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task

I am new to asynchronous programming in C#. Consider the following snippet.

```
    private static async Task TestAsync(int n)
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(() => Job(ConsoleColor.DarkRed, n));
        Job(ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
        await t;
        Job(ConsoleColor.DarkBlue);
    }
```

`t` is a task that repetitively prints its thread id with red background. `t` runs on a different thread.

In parallel, `Job(ConsoleColor.DarkGreen)` repetitively prints its thread id with green background. As it runs on the main thread, it always prints 1.

Finally, `Job(ConsoleColor.DarkBlue)` repetitively prints with blue background only after all red and green ids get printed. In my understanding the blue one must only print 1 because it runs on the main thread. However, when I increase the `n` from `10` to `90`, I got a contradictory result as follows.

[image]

When `n=90`, the blue one prints a number that is not the same as the main thread id.

## Question

Why does the code after `await` sometimes run on another thread?

## Minimal Working Example

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;

class Test
{
    static readonly object obj = new object();

    static void Print(string s, ConsoleColor bc = ConsoleColor.Black)
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            BackgroundColor = bc;
            ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Write(s);
            ResetColor();
        }
    }

    static void Job(ConsoleColor bc, int n = 50)
    {
        for (long x = 0; x < n; x++)
        {
            Print($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} ", bc);
        }
    }

    private static async Task TestAsync(int n)
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(() => Job(ConsoleColor.DarkRed, n));
        Job(ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
        await t;
        Job(ConsoleColor.DarkBlue);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int n = 10;
        Print($"When n = {n}.\n");
        TestAsync(n).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        n = 90;
        Print($"\n\n\nWhen n = {n}.\n");
        TestAsync(n).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see! That makes sense,I will retract my comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it can.

You `await`ed so if the `Task` wasn't already completed the thread you were running on went back to the pool, potentially to do something useful. Then the `Task` you were `await`ing finished, so a thread was needed to continue. There's no reason why it should be the same thread as before.